# Holding Torque of Nema Stepper Motor

Tags: printing, arduino, adafruit, stepper

I am working on a handmade 3D printer. I have two pieces of Nema - 11 Bipolar Stepper motor for my project and I want to connect it directly to vertical crank as in the picture. (There is no extra element such as stepper pulley) These steppers will carry a total of 40 kgs for movable bar.

[image: picture]

***This picture is an example.*** So, how can I calculate maximum total lifting weight of these two steppers? Is These steppers enough for this project? In another case, which type stepper can I choose for this 3D printer? Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: 40kg ??  Even 4kg is heavy for an entire 3d printer....  In any case, the screw will reduce the power needed.  You also have 2 motors, which will divide the power by 2 to start with.  Nema 11s may be a bit on the weak side, for raising the carriage.  Keep in mind that the screws will keep the carriage from coming down when the motors are powered down.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy It will be t-shirt printer but not so professional. Because of this, It's a little bit different from other 3D printer. It will include more component on vertical crank. This is why I need more torque for it.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is pretty off-topic I'll give you a few hints.

Basically all you have to do is google "ball screw force" or "ball screw torque"

http://www.nookindustries.com/LinearLibraryItem/Ballscrew_Torque_Calculations

There are also calculators available:

http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Lead-Screw-Force-Torque-Calculator.phtml

Comment: I made calculations in the direction of your information. As a result, I will carry 50 kgs, it approximately equals to 500 N. For 1 cm crankshaft, T= 0,01 x 500 = 5 Nm. So according to my figures, twice of these stepper will be enough for it :)